# How to reexpose an entire crate inline

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a proc-macro that also exposes some types, so I'm using the following crate structure:

- `foo_core` exports `FooTrait`
- `foo_macro` (depends on `foo_core`) exports `foo_macro`, which generates some structs that implement `FooTrait`
- `foo` (depends on `foo_core` and `foo_macro`) re-exports `FooTrait` and `foo_macro`

The problem I'm running into is that re-exporting `foo_core` changes it's path.

`foo_macro` generates code that looks roughly like:

```rust
struct Bar;

impl ::foo_core::FooTrait for Bar {
  // ...
}
```

I have a bunch of `trybuild` tests in `foo_macro` which pass, since `foo_core` is an available crate.

The problem is when I try to write tests in `foo` (or in crates that depend on `foo` only), I get the error telling me it can't find the crate `foo_core`.

This makes some sense to me; the consumer of `foo` hasn't explicitly depended on `foo_core`, but I'd like it if users of my crate didn't have to add `foo` and `foo_core` (and make sure the versions match), instead I'd like them to be able to add just `foo` and it would work.

Currently, I can access `foo_core` via `foo::foo_core::FooTrait`, but obviously this is different to how my macro generates the code (`::foo_core::FooTrait`). Is there a way to make `foo` re-export the entire `foo_core` crate?

If that's not possible, what's the best way of going about this pattern? Can I somehow make `foo_macro` change its behaviour depending on what crate it's defined in? Or should I just move all my tests to `foo` instead of `foo_macro`?

[Is there a way to have a public trait in a proc-macro crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64288426/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-public-trait-in-a-proc-macro-crate) An answer to this question mentions this problem, but simply says "you must use the fully-qualified names", but my understanding was that this is what the leading `::` on the path means.

This seems like a relatively common pattern, so I'm hoping there's a nice solution out there.

Comment: It seems to be similar situation like three crates in Rocket (rocket_codegen, rocket_http, and rocket ) https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/master/core.  So it seems that the lib `foo` in your case will re-export `foo_core` like rocket rexports `rocket_http` in `rocket` https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.5-rc/core/lib/src/lib.rs#L129-L141.  And so in your case your fully qualified names in generated and tested code would be `foo::foo_core::FooTrait`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `foo` crate, you can completely reexport `foo_core` with either:

- `pub extern crate foo_core;`
- `pub use foo_core;`

With either of those statements, all of `foo_core` can be accessed through `foo::foo_core::` when only having `foo` in the `[dependencies]` section of your `Cargo.toml`. Your proc macro would emit `::foo::foo_core::` paths then. This of course requires that users don't use `foo_macro` and `foo_core` directly. But this is common: usually, people are not supposed to use the macro crate directly, but only the "top level crate".

This is a common pattern, not only with your own crates. For example, in one of my libraries, my proc macro generates call to `serde` functions (not my library). So I `pub use serde;` in my crate so that users of my library don't have to depend on `serde` directly.